# Blender 2.8: Move (g) a face like in the direction, extrude would do, when object is "sheared"?

Tags: modeling

"Extrude" always extend a face in the direction of the face normal.
Having a "sheared" object (see below):
How can I acchieve the same behaviour when moving a face with "g"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it switching the transformation orientation to *'normal'*, then grab <kbd>G</kbd> and use <kbd>Z</kbd> to indicate the Z axis which is by convention the normal direction.

[image]